# Disable hidden object distances in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to measure the distance between multiple grouped items with the ruler tool (holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and pointing to another object). However, Photoshop also includes the distance from hidden elements and special objects like overlaps from clipping masks in its calculation.

Is there a way not to include these?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 2 options to do that:

1. Creating a shape layer exactly like the same mask, by hitting `Ctrl` + `J` while the layer is selected.
2. Calculate the distance **from** the clipping mask **to** the object, by selecting the clipping mask layer and holding `Ctrl` and pointing the desired object.

Comment: I want to calculate everything EXCEPT the clipping mask, because it's messing up the dimensions.

Comment: You don't want to include overlapping layers in measuring margins, paddings, etc. If it's that what's you're asking, try those two options and it should work.